# What is the health of a green square, triangle, or pentagon in diep.io?

Tags: diep.io

When looking at the diep.io achievements, I saw something that said

> Shiny ???

After searching up what it was, you apparently get the achievement by destroying a green square, triangle, or pentagon.

How much health does the square, triangle, and pentagon have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [diepio.fandom.com/wiki/Polygons](https://diepio.fandom.com/wiki/Polygons)

- A [green pentagon](https://diepio.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Pentagon) has 1000 HP and gives 13000 XP
- A [green triangle](https://diepio.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Triangle) has 300 HP and gives 2500 XP
- A [green square](https://diepio.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Square) has 100 HP and gives 1000 XP

I hope this helps! :)